Unable to Install Litmus Chaos 3.0 on Arm 64, M1 Apple computer
I am trying to install Litmus Chaos 3.0 on my local computer, but I could not find a suitable mongodb image for replacement.
I tried arm64v8/mongo, mongodb/mongodb-community-server, as well as other version of Mongo (6.0 nad 5.0) but they are still not working.
I try the kubernetes yaml file approach, but the the image that the official website gives it to me doesn't work properly.Or maybe i did not use the correct image
Does anyone know a suitable images or a way to install Litmus Chaos 3.0? Thanks!
First way of installing
`helm install chaos litmuschaos/litmus --namespace=litmus \
--set portal.frontend.service.type=NodePort \
--set mongodb.image.registry=docker.io \
--set mongodb.image.repository=mongo \
--set mongodb.image.tag=tag
`

